# How to handle concurrent POST request in selenium Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nodejs-server

How to handle concurrent POST requests?

Example Code

```
async function getPageContent(){
        
    await driver.get(profileURL);
        let headline = await driver
                .findElement(By.id("main"))
                .getText()
                .then((res) => {
                  return res;
                });
    }

user-1 : POST : www.google.com
user-2 : POST : www.facebook.com
user-3 : POST : www.amazon.com
user-4 : POST : www.azure.com
```

**How to handle these requests in selenium ?**

Comment: With fetch you mean?

Comment: I have a chrome selenium browser. ex: I have test facebook profile logged in. I'll get multiple profile URL as request how to handle it in selenium ?